# R / Compile c code for R

Tags: c++, r, cmd, include, rcpp

How can one include a c library for the compilation of c code for R when using R CMD SHLIB?

For example the c code needs:   #include Rcpp.h

How can I add the path of Rcpp.h when using R CMD SHLIB on the console in Windows 7?

"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2\bin\x64\R" CMD SHLIB -o test.so -I"C:\Users\R\win-library\3.1\Rcpp\include\Rcpp.h"  test.c

The description in "Writing R Extensions.pdf" was not understandable for me.

Thank you very much for every answer, I  appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R CMD SHLIB is not recommended; if you're writing  a package, I'd suggest using the method suggested in [part 2.4 of the Rcpp FAQ](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf).

Alternately, you might want to look into [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/) which (amongst its many awesome features) includes automatically handling that when you hit "source" (for individual C++ files) or "build and reload" (for entire packages)

Comment: Thank you very much. 
Yes, it's not recommanded. In part 2.4 of the Rcpp FAQ there is an explanation how to use RCMD SHLIB if very much wanted.                                                              $ export PKG_CXXFLAGS=`Rscript -e "Rcpp:::CxxFlags()"`
$ R CMD SHLIB myfile.cpp But I could not find out how to do this on windows. I will try RStudio. Thanks.

Comment: It is all in the documentation, including the FAQ and in more detail in the Rcpp book.

Comment: Ok. I could not find information how to compile under Windows including additional libraries other than mentioned above and I do not own the book. Compiling with RStudio works great! Thanks a lot. (It would be still interesting how to do this with the command prompt. From the output under RStudio the commmand should be as written in the question above. But it's obviously not.)